# Emacs: How do I detect which Python mode is running and select default Python interpreter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, emacs

> Emacs: How do I detect which Python mode is running and select default Python interpreter?

First of all, how do I see which Python mode is running?

I've read that multiple exist, like python-mode.el etc.

Secondly, pressing `C-c C-z` results in a `Run Python` dialog appearing. I use Python3 and I want this to be the default. So, instead of always editing `python` to `python3` in the path `/usr/bin/python -i`, how do I make this automatically?

Please resond so a newbie to Emacs can understand the details :-)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First off lets start off by finding out which python mode you're using. Generally unless you downloaded something and actively decided to use python-mode.el you won't be using it, instead you'll be using the great, built-in, python.el. If you didn't know this you could press  <kbd>C-h m</kbd>  to bring up the help menu for the mode that you're currently in. A bit down the page you'll notice that it says "Python mode is defined in 'python.el'". Neat!

Okay so choosing the interpreter is pretty easy. There is a variable called `python-shell-interpreter` you can set this variable to anything you want! For example you can set it to "python3", I personally have it set to "ipython". The code to place in your init file, is `(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3")`

If you have any other questions feel free to let me know!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What exactly is "ipython", and why don't I use this by default?

Comment: [Ipython](https://ipython.org/) lets you interact with python the same way that the normal interpretter does, I just think it looks prettier

Answer (score 0):

In your init file you can place the following:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "/usr/bin/python3")
```

so that Emacs will use Python 3 instead of Python 2. Here's [info on init files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) in case you don't know about them.